# Material designing issue in angular apps

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hi i am beginner for angular and i want to use material Basic Inputs fields in my application and i followed below blog to do my requirement https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview but when i run my code i am getting error

```
Template parse errors:
'mat-form-field' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-form-field' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-form-field' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the
```

Below i gave my stackblizz link please help me where did i do mistack

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ux8kqk

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api

Comment: you should import the MatFormFieldModule into app.module.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not imported `MatInputModule` in your `.module.ts`

Make following changes in your `app.module.ts`

`import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';`

```
imports : [
 // Other modules
 MatInputModule
]
```

Comment: Where should i import this can you please explain clearly?

Comment: check out your updated [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9fmaye). For more information check out [Angular docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) Step 3.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to import both `MatInputModule` from

```
 import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
```

as well as `MatFormFieldModule` from

```
 import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
```

at

```
@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule,MatInputModule, MatFormFieldModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

in `app.module.ts`.

`MatFormFieldModule` is for `<mat-form-field></mat-form-field>` and
    `MatInputModule` is for `matInput` used in input/textarea.
working
[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zq7uzv)